# passing data from database to highcharts in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, highcharts

What's the most elegant solution in Django to take data from database and pass it into Highcharts? I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810087/passing-django-database-queryset-to-highcharts-via-json), but I keep on getting the following error: JSerror: Invalid property id at `var chart_id = {{ chartID|safe }}`, if I try to use it in my example.

template looks like this:

```
<html>
<div id={{ chartID|safe }} class="chart" style="height: 100px; width: 500px"></div>
<script>
var chart_id = {{ chartID|safe }}
var series = {{ series|safe }}
var title = {{ title|safe }}
var xAxis = {{ xAxis|safe }}
var yAxis = {{ yAxis|safe }}
var chart = {{ chart|safe }}
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

In case there are better ways to pass data to highcharts please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are missing the quotes in your javascript:

```
var chart_id = "{{ chartID|safe }}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass your data as a context to the template, change it to a list in python. Then in your javascript block create a script tag then declare your data variables that you passed ,then pass them to your plotting script.