# Passing Django data to Highcharts via JSON

Tags: python, json, django, highcharts

**UPDATE:**

I've been trying to replicate the method used in [this solution thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810087/passing-django-database-queryset-to-highcharts-via-json) to display a Highcharts graph via Django, but in vain. I'm passing data from a python script to my *views.py* file, but the graph doesn't show up.

Below is what I get when I check *view source* in my browser. What am I missing in this html doc? The graph is not showing up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Head title here</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" type = "text/css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
          height:100%
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:95%; ">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <br>
                  <center>
                    <img src="/static/img/profile.jpg" class="responsive-img" style='max-height:100px;' alt="face">
                  </center>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <br>
                  <center>
                  <h3>Some stuff goes here</h3>
                  </center>
              </div>
        </div><hr>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
          <br>

          <br>
            <!-- Great, til you resize. -->
            <!--<div class="well bs-sidebar affix" id="sidebar" style="background-color:#fff">-->
            <div class="well bs-sidebar" id="sidebar" style="background-color:#fff">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='/blog/'>Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href='/contact/'>Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> <!--well bs-sidebar affix-->
          </div> <!--col-sm-2-->
          <div class="col-sm-10">

            <div class='container-fluid'>
            <br><br>

<body>
    <div id="chart_ID" class="chart" style="height:100px; width:100%"></div>
</body>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Original post:**

**my *my-app/views.py* file**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import python_script

def plot(request, chartID = 'chart_ID', chart_type = 'bar', chart_height = 500):

    data = python_script.chart_function()
    categories = python_script.chart_categories()
    chart = {"renderTo": chartID, "type": chart_type, "height": chart_height,}
    title = {"text": 'my title here'}
    xAxis = {"title": {"text": 'axis title here'}, "categories": categories}
    yAxis = {"title": {"text": 'axis title here'}}
    series = [
        {"name": 'Asia Pacific', "data": data['Asia Pacific']},
        {"name": 'CIS', "data": data['Commonwealth of Independent States']},
        {"name": 'Europe', "data": data['Europe']},
        {"name": 'Latin America', "data": data['Latin America']},
        {"name": 'MENA', "data": data['Middle East and North Africa']},
        {"name": 'Northern America', "data": data['Northern America']},
        {"name": 'SSA', "data": data['Sub-Saharan Africa']}
    ]

    return render(request, 'my-app/chart.html', {'chartID': chartID, 'chart': chart,
                                                'series': series, 'title': title,
                                                'xAxis': xAxis, 'yAxis': yAxis})
```

In my views.py file:

- the format of *data* is a dictionary: {'Asia Pacific':[1,2,3,4],'Europe':[1,2,3...], ...}
- the format of *categories* is a list of strings: ['A', 'B', ...]

**my *my-app/chart.html* file**

```
{% load compress %}
{% compress js %}
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}Highcharts-5.0.14/code/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}Highcharts-5.0.14/code/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
{% endcompress %}

{% block heading %}
    <h1 align="center">Analysis</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id={{ chartID|safe }} class="chart" style="height:100px; width:100%"></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block overwrite %}
<!-- Overwrite the base.html jQuery load and put in head for Highcharts to work -->
{% endblock %}

{% block extrajs %}
<!-- Maps the Python template context variables from views.py to the Highchart js variables -->
<script>
    var chart_id = {{ chartID|safe }}
    var chart = {{ chart|safe }}
    var title = {{ title|safe }}
    var xAxis = {{ xAxis|safe }}
    var yAxis = {{ yAxis|safe }}
    var series = {{ series|safe }}
</script>

<!-- Highchart js. Variable map shown above -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(chart_id).highcharts({
        chart: chart,
        title: title,
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        series: series
    });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**my *my-app/urls.py* file**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^graph/', views.plot, name = 'plot'),
]
```

**my *settings.py* file**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my-app',
    'highcharts',
    'jquery',
    'compressor',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
...
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have ran the command *python manage.py collectstatic* already.

Answer (score 1):

Directly rendering Python data structures like lists and dictionaries in your template to use them in JavaScript *can* work, but it is unreliable. Instead, convert them to JSON in your view:

```
import json
...
return render(request, 'my-app/chart.html',
              {'chartID': json.dumps(chartID), 'chart': json.dumps(chart),
               'series': json.dumps(series), 'title': json.dumps(title),
               'xAxis': json.dumps(xAxis), 'yAxis': json.dumps(yAxis)})
```

In you template, use the JSON like this:

```
var chartID = JSON.parse("{{ chartID|escapejs }}")
```

If that doesn't solve the issue, check the JavaScript console of your browser for error messages.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - it didn't solve it, but I checked the JavaScript console and it does show 4 alerts for each static file I'm loading, the alerts say: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Apparently your static files do not contain valid JavaScript, that sounds to me like the files cannot be loaded correctly. Check the URL in page source and see what it returns.

Comment: BTW, it is a good idea to update your original question with these findings so others can easier follow along and chime in.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - you're correct, in view source, the page displays exactly the code as it's written in the chart.html file above. The first line says <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>. It doesn't seem to be interpreting the page as <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I just realized that your template probably extends another template, but misses an `{% extends ... %}` tag in the first.

Comment: @DanielHepper you should include in your snippet how to use the json, e.g., `<script> var chart_data = JSON.parse("{{ chart|escapejs }}") </script>`

Comment: thanks @Jiaaro, I've tried your approach without success. How would you recommend implementing? Also, I wonder if I'm missing something in my *chart.html* file in the {block overwrite} section ... could that be?