# "Didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead" on POST request

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to pass a selection from a dropdown form into views as a POST request, then using this selection to query some data from django. I'm then using these queries to try and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810087/passing-django-database-queryset-to-highcharts-via-json) approach to map django models data to highcharts. The problem is I'm getting a "the view properties.views.property_list didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead" error when I submit the form. I've looked through similar questions on SO but none of the solutions seem to work/be applicable to my case. Perhaps my form is invalid, though I'm not sure what's causing that to be the case. Below is the code that I've written:

views.py

```
def property_list(request):

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    current_user_groups = Group.objects.filter(id__in=request.user.groups.all())
    current_user_properties = Property.objects.filter(groups__in=current_user_groups)
    current_user_meters = Meter.objects.filter(meter_id__in=current_user_properties)
    property_meter_data = MeterData.objects.filter(meter__in=current_user_meters)

    class AccountSelectForm(forms.Form):
        accounts = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=current_user_meters)
        accounts.widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'dropdown-content'})

    form = AccountSelectForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            selection = form.cleaned_data['accounts']

            current_user_groups = Group.objects.filter(id__in=request.user.groups.all())
            current_user_properties = Property.objects.filter(groups__in=current_user_groups)
            current_user_meters = Meter.objects.filter(meter_id__in=current_user_properties)

            selected_meters = Meter.objects.filter(name=selection)
            selected_meter_data = MeterData.objects.filter(name=selection)

            usage_data = {'usage': [], 'dates': []}

            for meter in selected_meter_data:
                usage_data['usage'].append(meter.usage)
                usage_data['dates'].append(meter.usage)

            # data passing for usage chart

            usage_xAxis = {"title": {"text": 'Date'}, "categories": usage_data['dates']}
            usage_yAxis = {"title": {"text": 'Usage'}, "categories": usage_data['usage']}
            usage_series = [
                {"data": usage_data['usage']},
            ]

            return HttpResponseRedirect('properties/property-selected.html', {
                'form': form,
                'usage_xAxis': usage_xAxis, 
                'usage_yAxis': usage_yAxis, 
                'usage_series': usage_series,
                'current_user_meters': current_user_meters,
                'selection': selection,
                'selectected_meters': selected_meters,
                'selected_meter_data': selected_meter_data,
            })

    else:

        current_user_groups = Group.objects.filter(id__in=request.user.groups.all())
        current_user_properties = Property.objects.filter(groups__in=current_user_groups)
        current_user_meters = Meter.objects.filter(meter_id__in=current_user_properties)
        property_meter_data = MeterData.objects.filter(meter__in=current_user_meters)

        return render(request, 'Properties/properties.html',{
        'form': form,
        'current_user_groups': current_user_groups,
        'current_user_properties': current_user_properties,
        'current_user_meters': current_user_meters,
        'property_meter_data': property_meter_data
    })

else:

    # If the usre isn't authenticated, the user is redirected to the Sign-n Page

    return render(request, 'SignIn/SignInPage.html')
```

template.html

```
<!-- Query based content for dropdown menu -->
<form method="POST" action="" id="property-select">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.accounts }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" style="margin-top:30px;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: When the request method is POST, you should instantiate the form with `form = AccountSelectForm(request.POST)`. At the moment, the form is not bound to any data, so it will never be valid.

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

If method=='POST' and your form is invalid, nothing is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've edited to add the code from my template, any idea why my form would be invalid? I'm not sure why it'd be the case.

Comment: Why don't you display the form errors in the template, then you (and the user) will know why it's invalid.